# yocto devtool change ":portnumber" to "/portnumber" in URI, how to fix it?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

The command I executed:

`devtool add --srcbranch master hello ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.com.cn:22222/cjl/hello.git`

but error shows:

```
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PATH="...omit"; export HOME="...omit"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.com.cn/22222/cjl/hello.git  failed with exit code 128, output:
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.ucas.com.cn: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It resolves my URI to **ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.com.cn/22222/cjl/hello.git**(:22222 to /22222)

I'm sure that:

1. `git clone ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.com.cn:22222/cjl/hello.git` in bash is ok.
2. `git://git@gitlab.xxxx.com.cn:22222/cjl/hello.git;protocol=ssh` in other bbfile is ok.

**so, why devtool change :port to /port?**
yocto version: rocko 2.4